# Is it possible to duplicate a GDI handle?

Tags: c++, c, windows, gdi

Or in my particular case a windows region (HRGN)?

Updated:
The problems is the following:

I've a collection of objects, each of these objects can hold a HRGN. These region once acquired is released when the object is destroyed. Since some of those objects are stored in a std::vector I've to define an assignement operator.

Until now I've just assigned those HRGN, but that is a bug. If I duplicate such objects each one of those will try to delete the same region, and one of those wil be using a non existent region.

Comment: Why do you want to duplicate the handle?  There is probably a solution to your problem, but you need to give more context (and possibly code snippets).

Comment: Thanks, I've added some of the context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap each HRGN in a reference-counting object modeled after any smart pointer e.g. `shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot make a duplicate of HRGN handle, but you could get a copy using [`CombineRgn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa922002.aspx) function.

Comment: I though of that using RGN_COPY, but I didn't know how to create an empty region.

Comment: Bad idea, GDI heap is very limited at least on older OSes.

Comment: It is limited ( [more about it](http://blogs.technet.com/markrussinovich/archive/2010/03/31/3322423.aspx) ) but the one region requires a very small amount of that memory.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not possible. GDI objects support only a single handle per object.

Comment: I hoped I was missing some api call, seem that the correction solution is to keep a reference counting myself. Thank you.